# Mongodb update array object after sorting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

My document is like shown below

```
{
    WORKFLOWS: [
      {
        ID: 1,
        STARTEDBY: "BOBU",
        ACTIVE: true,
        HISTORY: [
          {
            STATS: 21,
            DATE_TIME: "2020-03-19T00:16:39.612Z",
            USER: "VICTORIA",
          },
          {
            STATS: 20,
            DATE_TIME: "2020-03-19T00:16:40.190Z",
            USER: "VICTORIA",
            REMINDER: [
              "2020-03-19T00:13:39.709Z",
              "2020-03-19T00:16:39.612Z",
              "2020-03-19T00:16:40.190Z",
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
```

What I am trying to achieve is to find the latest history object and create **REMINDER** property if not existing and **push** the current date-time as a string

Since I am going to call this from node, i can send the current time from node as a parameter

Regards
 Bobu

Answer (score 0):

Well, we need to do it in two steps.

### Explanation

1. We need to find the recent `DATE_TIME` with `$addFields`.

```
var MAX_DT = "1970-01-01T00:00:00:00.000Z";
for(var dt in WORKFLOWS[*].HISTORY[*].DATE_TIME){
    MAX_DT = MAX_DT > dt ? MAX_DT : dt
}
```

2. In the next step, we iterate over `WORKFLOWS` and `HISTORY` arrays with `$map` operator and add current date with [$$NOW](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.NOW) (Standalone) or [$$CLUSTER_TIME](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.CLUSTER_TIME) (Cluster). 
   `$dateToString` allows specify `timezone` to customize `HH:MM` result.
3. If you want to persist the result, just add as the last step `$out` operator:

   {$out:"collection"}

   <sub>**Note:** It will override entire collection with aggregation result.</sub>

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "MAX_DT": {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$WORKFLOWS.HISTORY.DATE_TIME",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {
                $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ]
              }
            }
          },
          initialValue: "1970-01-01T00:00:00:00.000Z",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $gt: [ "$$value", "$$this" ]
              },
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "WORKFLOWS": {
        $map: {
          input: "$WORKFLOWS",
          as: "wf",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$wf",
              {
                HISTORY: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$wf.HISTORY",
                    as: "his",
                    in: {
                      $cond: [
                        {
                          $eq: [ "$$his.DATE_TIME", "$MAX_DT" ]
                        },
                        {
                          $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$his",
                            {
                              REMINDER: {
                                $concatArrays: [
                                  {
                                    $ifNull: [ "$$his.REMINDER", [] ]
                                  },
                                  [
                                    {
                                      $dateToString: {
                                        date: "$$NOW",
                                        timezone: "+02:00"
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$his"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RgEBzFnznoA)